# What would be the best way of doing this floral pattern on a letter without drawing skills?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image: This]

I want to try and do this for a photography freelancer I am doing a logo for. What is the best way of making my own floral pattern?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can start the illustration making several petals **Pattern Brushes**, apply them to a circle and then combine them randomly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go with stock images, as its very likely somebody else is already selling something very similar. Look up 'floral pattern' on shutterstock.

Answer (score 0):

"Your own pattern" obviously excludes purchasing it, you want to compose it by yourself.

Search for floral clipart. There's available free and paid collections. If you are lucky, you can already have usable shapes as bonus clipart which is included in many pieces of software. Clipart can have single flowers as well as patterns and both can be used. Often it's possible to explode a complex clipart shape and take what you want, but sometimes that can be made difficult for technical or business reasons.

If you use clipart, do not use photos, but vectors. It's useful to make a logo as vector drawing (Illustrator, Inkscape) because you have more flexible tools for free composition and everything is freely scalable without making it blurry or pixelated.

Vector drawing software have tools for vectorizing (=tracing) photos, but that process need high quality photos and the result is unsure. I recommend to start from clipart, if you are a beginner.

Clipart has one problem: A well composed high quality photo, which you see somewhere, can easily catch your attention and then no clipart seems interesting enough. But remember, you wanted to make your own pattern.

Recoloring and making it BW is possible in vector drawing software.

You have learn how to use a vector drawing program. Even, if you use clipart and have a clear idea,  you need a week if you start from skill level zero.